# How do I format a column but keep it as datetime?

Tags: sql-server, formatting

This may be the dumbest question, but I have a column called [Start Time] which is (datetime, not null) and outputs data in the form '2016-05-25 00:12:01.977'

What I want is to snip everything except the Month and Year and group data into months. What I used is

```
select format([Start Time],'MMM/yyyy') as [Month]
```

Which worked fine except that it seems now no longer to be a datetime field and when I add

```
order by format([Start Time],'MMM/yyyy')
```

It puts the months in alphabetical order rather than Jan Feb etc. I tried using

```
convert(date,format([Start Time],'MMM/yyyy'))
```

but that brought back the error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to maintain the date data type when formatting and grouping by month and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: what do you achieve with  grouping, count the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling dates in SQL Server require a little bit work, but you can get around your problem by changing the dates first to the 1st of the month, grouping with that, and then finally format it, something like this:

```
select
  format(Month2,'MMM/yyyy') as Month,
  amount
from
(
  select
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0) as Month2,
    sum(amount) as amount
  from
    yourtable
  group by
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0)
) X
order by
  Month2
```

Format is also quite heavy operation, you should consider using convert or datepart if you have a lot of rows.

Comment: So I tried `select
  format(Month,'MMM/yyyy') as Month,
  [Calls Offered],
  [Calls Answered]
from
(
  select
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0) as Month,

sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call','Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [Calls Offered],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered]

From inboundcallsview 

group by
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0)
 ) X

 Order by Month` but still got alphabetical order.

Comment: If convert or datepart would work better I'd be happy for answers to use them. I only used format because I knew it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the same alias for the month in inner and outer query, and of course then the order by doesn't really work. I updated the query now.

Answer (score 1):

```
select format([Start Time],'MMM/yyyy') as [Month]
order by month([Start Time]), year([Start Time])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this :

```
Declare @t table(dtvalue datetime)

insert into @t values ('2016-05-01 00:12:01.977'), ('2016-05-06 00:12:01.977'), ('2016-05-10 00:12:01.977'), ('2016-05-15 00:12:01.977'),
 ('2016-05-25 00:12:01.977'), ('2016-06-25 00:12:01.977'), ('2016-06-28 00:12:01.977')

--select * from @t

select dtvalue,
format(dtvalue,'MMM/yyyy')
 from @t
group by  dtvalue

insert into @t values ('2016-05-02 00:12:01.977')

select dtvalue,
format(dtvalue,'MMM/yyyy')
 from @t
group by  dtvalue

/*Count the record in a month via grouping*/
select count (format(dtvalue,'MMM/yyyy')),
format(dtvalue,'MMM/yyyy')
 from @t
group by  format(dtvalue,'MMM/yyyy')
```

Comment: You don't have order by, so the results are in random order

Comment: no need to order by when you group by the value. Please add some rows to understand

Comment: Well OP wanted the rows in order of the months, so there is a need to order them